# Use get cookies for post request

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, request

I want to make a get request and then use the data I got back to make a post request but with this code all i get is the following error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

This code works as long as the headers are not included, but it does not hit the endpoint.

```
import requests
import asyncio
import json

url = 'https://test.com/add/login'
g = requests.get(url)
myHeaders = g.headers
print(myHeaders)
myCokies = g.cookies.get('Session')
print(myCokies)

myData = {'username':'test','password':'test'}
myCokies = dict(MoodleSession=myCokies)
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(myData), cookies=myCokies)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: At first glance without trying to run it, your code looks alright. That error message indicates to me that the url/server you are hitting is not responding to the request.

Comment: Do you know If the headers are important in a POST request? @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim

Comment: Depends on the server really. I've made requests that only care about the data passed and I've made some that require the header to be set. I've built back end code that's done both. Like I said depends on what the server is supposed to do.

Comment: Because repeating the request in Burp works perfectly but making the request in python without the headers does not hit the end point, so i am going crazy. I have edited the code.